# Powershell WebRequest GET Succeeds but DELETE fails w/ 404

Tags: rest, powershell, httpwebrequest

Very confused on this issue. Here is what I am dealing with currently.

I have an API endpoint which looks like this `/subscriptions/:id`. This endpoint serves as both a `GET` & a `DELETE` endpoint. When I run a GET, it returns the object as it normally does, but changing the action to a DELETE gives me back a 404 for the very same resource which was just returned in the GET, I don't know why.

Here is my Powershell code.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$user         = '*********'
$pass         = ConvertTo-SecureString '*********' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred         = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass
$base         = "https://*********.hosted.xmatters.com/api/xm/1"


$del_path = "$base/subscriptions/********uuid***********"
$path     = "$base/subscriptions"
$payload  = @{
    id    = '********uuid***********'
    description = '**** NEW DESCRIPTION ****'
}

$params = $payload | ConvertTo-Json

// **** SUCCESS
$thing = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $del_path -Method GET

// **** FAILS
$thing = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $del_path -Method DELETE

// **** FAILS
$thing = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $path -Method POST -Body $params -ContentType 'application/json'
```

So, like mentioned previously, I am POSITIVE that the resource exists from the API. I am able to get it when running a GET but both POST (to update) & DELETE throw 404 errors. Here is the error I get.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At \\mmfile\ct32373$\Appsense\Desktop\Line of Business Revisions.ps1:24 char:10
+ $thing = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $del_path -Method D ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebReque 
   st) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman 
   ds.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The strange thing is that I am able to run the DELETE request successfully using POSTMAN, however because of the volume of data I need to process, this is not a good option

Comment: Have you tried using `Invoke-RestMethod` instead? I had similar problems deleting with `Invoke-WebRequest` which is why I use _RestMethod_ instead

Comment: I have, yes. Even still, the problem persists. I am flat out of ideas for the cause.

Comment: Have you tried the same with another tool, like e.g. Postman. What I mean is, are you sure it is a powershell issue. Sometimes it is also good to use Fiddler, to check what went in the wire. Often solves so many mysteries.

Comment: Yea, actually this *does* work in Postman, which makes me all the more confused because now I know this is a Powershell issue. Just not sure why an identical endpoint, but with different verbs (GET vs DELETE) would yield 1) a valid response and 2) a 404 to the very same endpoint. Why the heck would that be the case? And it's not a permissions issue because I have the highest level role capable of doing all actions throughout the entire API, so I can remove that from list of possibles